# gulp-imagemin не сжимает картинки

Tags: node.js, gulp, npm

Почему-то `gulp-imagemin` не сжимает нормально картинки загрузил 2,24Mb картинку, а оно ужало буквально на пару килобайт, что в моем `gulpfile.js` не так, или может не лучший вариант для сжатия картинок

```
"use strict";

var gulp             = require('gulp'),
    sass         = require('gulp-sass'), //Подключаем Sass пакет,
    sourcemaps   = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    concat       = require('gulp-concat'),// Подключаем gulp-concat (для конкатенации файлов)
    uglify       = require('gulp-uglifyjs'),// Подключаем gulp-uglifyjs (для сжатия JS)
    browserSync  = require('browser-sync'),// Подключаем Browser Sync
    imagemin     = require('gulp-imagemin'), // Подключаем библиотеку для работы с изображениями
    pngquant     = require('imagemin-pngquant'), // Подключаем библиотеку для работы с png
    rename       = require('gulp-rename'), // Подключаем библиотеку для переименования файлов
    cache        = require('gulp-cache'), // Подключаем библиотеку кеширования
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),// Подключаем библиотеку для автоматического добавления префиксов
    del          = require('del'); // Подключаем библиотеку для удаления файлов и папок;

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.sass')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 9'], { cascade: true }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function () {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'dist'
        },
        notify: false
    });
});

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    return gulp.src([
        'app/js/common.js'
    ])
    .pipe(concat('main.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});

gulp.task('img', ['clean'], function () {
    return gulp.src('app/images/**/*')
    .pipe(cache(imagemin({
        optimizationLevel: 7,
        interlaced: true,
        progressive: true,
        svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
        use: [pngquant()]
    })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'));
});

gulp.task('clean', function() {
    return del.sync('dist/images/*');
});

gulp.task('clear', function() {
   return cache.clearAll();
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.sass',['sass']);
    gulp.watch('app/images/**/*',['img']);
    gulp.watch('dist/*.html', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js',['scripts', browserSync.reload] );
});

gulp.task('default', ['img', 'sass', 'scripts', 'browser-sync', 'watch']);
```

Comment: Почему вы уверены что несжимает? Хорошо сжимаются несжатые bmp, а уже сжатые картинки можно пытаться пересжать - но особого смысла нету (пару килобайт). И размер тут не показатель.

Comment: я из photoshop сохраняю как для web, когда я её ужимаю через сайт http://www.jpegmini.com/ к примеру, он ужимает больше чем в 2 раза, вот у меня и сомнения что gulp-imagemin ужимает хорошо. у меня правильно вообще написан таск, или есть ошибки какие то? + к этому в консоле не пишет что произошло сжатие на такой-то процент http://prntscr.com/e9v81t а по моему должно писать, судя по тому что я видел у людей в интернете

Comment: gulp-imagemin: Minified 8 images (saved 20 B - 10%) такого у меня не показывает((( вот от сюда и возник вопрос ужимает ли он вообще

Answer (score 1):

```
gulp.task('img:opt', function (callback) {
console.log('---------- Оптимизация картинок');
return gulp.src(dirs.srcPath + '/img/**/*.{jpg,jpeg,gif,png,svg,JPG}')
  .pipe(imagemin({
    progressive: true,
    optimizationLevel: 10,
    svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
    use: [pngquant()]
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(dirs.buildPath + '/img')); });
```

Попробуй, вот так показывает, но сжимает плохо